# Want to Make a Jar file

Tags: jar, executable-jar

I've made a java application(it extends JPanel) and want to make it into a jar file.I have BlueJ and I used it to do so but after I make the jar file it doesn't open. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't open? It's not in a zip format?

Comment: I don't know...I just made my java application into a jar file using BlueJ but when I try to open it, it doesn't open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jar files are PKZIP packaged files which have specific folder structure and convention in it. It contains the compiled version of your java sources (*.java -> *.class) plus meta data. You can "open" it with any archive which can handle zip files especially if you append the ".zip" extension to the file name.

If you mean executing your jar by "opening" it, that's a different thing. You have to have a standard static main method in one of your classes so the JVM can find the execution entrance point. If you have that you can say "java -jar yourjarfile.jar", which will execute your class starting from your main. Note, that I assume that you have JVM setup well (I guess you have) and your environment variables should be configured too. In most cases, your jar refers to other jar files. You can provide access for those for the JVM through classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Eclipse to write code? If you do, then it is easy to use Eclipse to create an executable jarfile.

Do you use a JFrame to present your JPanel? If you do not, you may have a JFrame, it is the "application window" where the JPanel will be presented.

JFrame tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

/Johan

Comment: I have never used BlueJ but I've had the same problem when I made an executable file with eclipse and have experienced that it may depend on the order in which you build up the GUI. For example, what order you add gui components to the JFrame in the code